# CSS3/HTML5 changing the border

Tags: css

I am curious if it is possible to move the top border and lower border automatically closer to the text? Is that possible or is this it?

[image]

Comment: Make sure your padding is all set to zero.

Comment: Check your line height & padding.

Comment: If I do not have a padding, will that be considered as that I do not have a padding?

Comment: Look in the dev tools to see what the layout actually is.

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please so that we can see what you're working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the padding .  For example

```
padding-top: 2px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
```

Comment: I "forced" the padfing so it is 0px. It should be enough when showing that I did what I could. All the other parameters are 0px. I will up vote you after the cut off. Thanks to all the other people engaged into this "big problem".

Answer (score 0):

if you do not specify a padding the browser will set it to the default value 0px;
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You only have to remove the vertical padding from the Text-Element, so if it's for example a span, like:

```
<span>Über mich</span>
```

then you only have to apply a y-padding of 0:

```
span { padding: 0 auto; }
```

that's it :)